# What happens to mains voltage in the event of a short circuit

Tags: mains

I mean before it trips the circuit breaker.

Comment: Don’t you want to define what level of action in your question, mechanical, electromagnetic forces, voltage transient, current transient

Answer (score 2):

If the short-circuit is an **ideal** short then the voltage drops to zero at the location of the short. If it's not an ideal short circuit then the voltage will drop but the actual voltage will depend on the resistance of the branch wiring and the resistance of the short itself.

What happens at other points along the branch will depend on the length the wires and their gauge. The voltage along the line will almost certainly decrease but determining how much the voltage will change is not a trivial problem and would require detailed information that you have not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Division by zero ohms is impossible but breakers are rated for 10kA.  “everything has resistance.” Even if measured in micro ohms.

if you shorted AWG16 insulated  copper wire with a 2mm to 5 mm thick screwdriver using a staple for leverage trying to remove it from wood, and instead puncturing the insulation at least 5mm of plated alloy tip screw driver will instantly vaporize cooler before the breaker trips causing an explosion from breaking the sound barrier with exploding evaporation of copper and steel.

This happens in 1 cycle due to a strong solenoid inside the breaker response time with high current and the vaporized copper junction  will leave a fine spray paint of copper on your plastic safety lens melted into the plastic.  I have personal experience doing this in my late 20’s building a Rec Room in my 1st house.  Good thing I wear glasses.  There are a lot more micro chain reactions ,but you get the idea.

When you simply exceed the breaker rating slowly, it heats up a bimetallic strip inside to bend and trip the breaker latch.

You can tell which breakers are wearing out by the handle temperature feeling warm from being aged by using most of the breaker rating.

The grid has a very low impedance and the transmission line impedance of a large LdI/dt =V is predictable for local 2nd order ringing effects.  The power meter has an internal arc point rated for 6kV at high current.